# What are the ways to improve the performance for below query

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below table query which is executed to get the latest REG_LOG(table) update, perform full table scan to get the results.

```
SELECT REG_PATH, 
       REG_USER_ID, 
       REG_LOGGED_TIME, 
       REG_ACTION, 
       REG_ACTION_DATA 
FROM REG_LOG  
WHERE REG_LOGGED_TIME > <last-access-time> 
     AND REG_LOGGED_TIME < '<current-time>' 
     AND REG_TENANT_ID = <tenant-id>
```

This table can contain millions of data. 
My question is what are the things we can do to increase the performance of this query? As per a workaround we have created an index for REG_LOGGED_TIME column to reduce full table scan.

Comment: Why is the index a workaround? Seems like a very good option to speed up a query...

Comment: Yes, What else we can do to improve the speed?

Comment: Couple of questions. Have you looked at your explain plan to see where the delay may be e.g. full table scans etc. How many rows are in REG_LOG? Without much further info, ideal candidate for index would be REG_TENANT_ID as it is an equality operation rather than range. Finally, I'm curious, is this Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server or DB2?

Comment: Please tell us how many distinct `REG_TENANT_ID` exists and what is the total range of `REG_LOGGED_TIME`.

Comment: REG_TENANT_ID can normally vary between 1 and 100, REG_LOGGED_TIME always will be a unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 2 fields in WHERE clause. There is first candidates for indexing. 
You should analyze selectivity of you fields. It is count distinct values divided by number rows. If result number is more then 200, you must create indexes.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX ON REG_LOG (REG_TENANT_ID, REG_LOGGED_TIME);
```

Also you should review your other queries against this table. Probably you should create just one composite index. In this case, the first field must be column with biggest selectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an the following index will significantly improve the speed of your query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON REG_LOG (REG_TENANT_ID, REG_LOGGED_TIME);
```

Comment: How can you be sure without seeing the current query plan and table statistics? What if the cardinality of `REG_LOG.REG_TENANT_ID` is very low?

Comment: @mustaccio if it's very low, the queries will be faster nonetheless, but at the expense of a bigger index than on date alone, which could prove almost as good.

Comment: Again, pure speculation. Low cardinality indices are unlikely to be chosen by the optimizer, so why queries would be faster in the presense of an unused index?

Comment: @mustaccio an index on REG_TENANT_ID alone would not be used for that query if the field has low cardinality, but a second field present in the index, with high cardinality and that is filtered by a query for a range, then it should be selected because it will be the optimum way to get to the information in the least number of searches and without results that would require further filtering. I.e. for an index, the relevant cardinality is that of the combination of all of the elements involved in its use, and the number of segments that will be required to scan. In this case, just one.